# Javascript Interview on promises

Tags: javascript, promise

This is a question I got asked in an interview. I know the array would just return zeros since this is asynchronous, but why does this happen, and how can you fix it so that the results array inserts the appropriate data?

**Question:** Suppose findData is a function that takes a query object and returns a promise for the result of the query. Suppose also that someRandomArrayOfQueries is an array of query objects. Explain what would be printed by the following code and why:

```
function runMultipleQueries(queries) {
 var results = [];
 queries.forEach(doQuery);

 return results;

 function doQuery(query) {
   findData(query)
   .then(results.push.bind(results));
 } 
}

function log(value) {
 console.log(value);
}

runMultipleQueries(someRandomArrayOfQueries).forEach(log);
```

Comment: Are you sure this is _vanilla JavaScript_?

Comment: you need read about asynchronous process javascript. The important here is you don´t know about the timing will be spend findData. The promise don´t block the process. A promise is only a promise that when He have the data He will execute the code inside then, or error inside catch. The return function will be execute previous any then because the javascript process continue the line of the code.

Comment: @PaulS. The code looks ok.

Comment: I think we are assuming that the findData(query) takes a long time in this case since they are trying to test your knowledge of single-threaded javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`doQuery` is executed at some point in the future. The array however is returned and logged immediately. Therefore the array is still empty and nothing is being logged.
To fix this `runMultipleQueries` needs to return a promise as well. That could e.g. look like this.

```
function runMultipleQueries(queries) {
  return Promise.all(queries.map(findData));
}
function log(value) {
 console.log(value);
}

runMultipleQueries(someRandomArrayOfQueries).then(function(results) {
    results.forEach(log);
});
```

If you wanted to keep `runMultipleQueries` similar to the original you could also create a new Promise like this, but that would be unnecessarily complex.

```
function runMultipleQueries(queries) {
 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
   var results = [];
   queries.forEach(doQuery);

   function doQuery(query) {
     findData(query)
     .then(function(result) {
         results.push(result);
         if(results.length === queries.length) resolve(results);
     }, reject);
   }
 });
}
```

You could also log the results inside `doQuery` but then you'll have no guarantee over the order in which the results are logged. Also that would make it more difficult to do anything else with those results after you logged them.

```
function runMultipleQueries(queries) {
  queries.forEach(doQuery);

  function log(value) {
    console.log(value);
  }
  function doQuery(query) {
    findData(query)
    .then(log);
  } 
}

runMultipleQueries(someRandomArrayOfQueries);
```

Comment: could I also fix it by adding a console log within the promise? Can one do that?

Comment: You could do that - I've added another example. But I would advise against it.